# How to get the matched employee details in a single search without looping

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a two json array for employee personal and company details. 
  Based on the value give in input field, I match both the tables and display the corresponding employees personal and company details in a single table.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script>
    var employee= 
       {
  "EmployeesPersonalDetails" : 
    [
       {
           "employeeID":01,
           "region":"Coimbatore",
           "phoneNumber":9087653456,
           "emailAddress":"abc@gmail.com"
       },
       {

           "employeeID":02,
           "region":"Avinashi",
           "phoneNumber":8990908765,
           "emailAddress":"def@gmail.com"
       },
       {
           "employeeID":03,
           "region":"Thippur",
           "phoneNumber":9089898990,
           "emailAddress":"ghi@gmail.com"
       },
       {
           "employeeID":04,
           "region":"Madurai",
           "phoneNumber":9012345990,
           "emailAddress":"jkl@gmail.com"
       },
       {
           "employeeID":05,
           "region":"Thippur",
           "phoneNumber":9067890990,
           "emailAddress":"mno@gmail.com"
       },
       {
           "employeeID":06,
           "region":"Thippur",
           "phoneNumber":9345218990,
           "emailAddress":"pqr@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
    }

var empcmpy={
"EmployeesCompanyDetails" :[
    {   
                "name" : "Mike",
                "employeeID" : 01,
                "designation" : "Software engineer"
    },
    {
                "name" : "Westlee",
                "employeeID" : 02,
                "designation" : "Software engineer trainee"
    },
    {   
                "name" : "Denise",
                "employeeID" : 03,
                "designation" : "Software test engineer"
    },

        {       "name" : "Matthew",
                "employeeID" : 04,
                "designation" : "Software Test engineer trainee"
    },
    {   
                "name" : "Mark",
                "employeeID" : 05,
                "designation" : "Project Manager"
    },
    {   
                "name" : "Karla",
                "employeeID" : 06,
                "designation" : "Associate Project Manager "
    }
]
}
function employeeDetails(){
      var eID = document.getElementById('eid').value; 
      var flag = false; 
         if(eID != "" ){
               for(i=0;i<employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails.length;i++){
                  for(j=0;j<empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails.length;j++){
                       if(employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails[i].employeeID == eID && empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails[j].employeeID == eID ){
                            flag=true;
                            document.getElementById('pro2').style.display = "block";
                            var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails[j].name + "</td>" 
                                         +"<td>" + empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails[j].employeeID + "</td>"  
                                         + "<td>" + employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails[i].phoneNumber + "</td>" 
                                         +"<td>" + employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails[i].emailAddress + "</td>"
                                         +"<td>" + empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails[j].designation + "</td>"
                                         +"<td>" + employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails[i].region + "</td>" 
                                         + "</tr>";
                            $(tblRow).appendTo("#employee1 tbody");
                        }
                    }
                }
                 if(flag==false)
                     alert ("Not matched");
            }

         else 
            {
                alert ("Emp id is empty");
            }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div>
Enter Emp id : <input type ="text" id="eid" name="eid"/>
<button id="getEmpdetails" onclick="employeeDetails()"> GetEmployeeDetails</button>
</div>
<div id ="pro2" class="profile2" style="display:none;">
 </br>  <table id= "employee1" border="2">
  <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th> Phone Number</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
       </tbody>
   </table>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used two loops for doing these, to find the nth employee it has to loop n times. how can i optimize it.

**UPDATE:**

```
function employeeDetails(){
      var eID = document.getElementById('eid').value; 
      var flag = 1; 
         if(eID != "" ){
               for(i=0;i<employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails.length;i++){
                       if(employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails[i].employeeID == eID ){
                            flag++;
                            document.getElementById('pro2').style.display = "block";
                            var tblRow = "<tr>"
                                         + "<td>" + employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails[i].phoneNumber + "</td>" 
                                         +"<td>" + employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails[i].emailAddress + "</td>"
                                         +"<td>" + employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails[i].region + "</td>";
                            $(tblRow).appendTo("#employee1 tbody");
                        }
                }
                 for(j=0;j<empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails.length;j++){
                       if( empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails[j].employeeID == eID ){
                            flag++;
                            document.getElementById('pro2').style.display = "block";
                            var tblRow =  "<td>" + empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails[j].name + "</td>" 
                                         +"<td>" + empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails[j].employeeID + "</td>"  

                                         +"<td>" + empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails[j].designation + "</td>";
                            $(tblRow).appendTo("#employee1 tbody");
                        }
                    }
                 if(flag!=3)
                     alert ("Not matched");
            }

         else 
            {
                alert ("Emp id is empty");
            }
    }
```

Comment: I do not see why you need a loop inside a loop, two separate loops should do the job

Comment: how can i do with the single loop

Comment: By using loop inside loop you are making the time complexity to n^2 but if you do it with 2 separate loop you can do it with a time complexity of 2n.

Comment: see the update which i posted. is this you have told ?

Comment: yes this a definitely an improvement over the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will be better.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   
    var employee= 
       {
  "EmployeesPersonalDetails" : 
    [
       {
           "employeeID":01,
           "region":"Coimbatore",
           "phoneNumber":9087653456,
           "emailAddress":"abc@gmail.com"
       },
       {

           "employeeID":02,
           "region":"Avinashi",
           "phoneNumber":8990908765,
           "emailAddress":"def@gmail.com"
       },
       {
           "employeeID":03,
           "region":"Thippur",
           "phoneNumber":9089898990,
           "emailAddress":"ghi@gmail.com"
       },
       {
           "employeeID":04,
           "region":"Madurai",
           "phoneNumber":9012345990,
           "emailAddress":"jkl@gmail.com"
       },
       {
           "employeeID":05,
           "region":"Thippur",
           "phoneNumber":9067890990,
           "emailAddress":"mno@gmail.com"
       },
       {
           "employeeID":06,
           "region":"Thippur",
           "phoneNumber":9345218990,
           "emailAddress":"pqr@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
    }

var empcmpy={
"EmployeesCompanyDetails" :[
    {   
                "name" : "Mike",
                "employeeID" : 01,
                "designation" : "Software engineer"
    },
    {
                "name" : "Westlee",
                "employeeID" : 02,
                "designation" : "Software engineer trainee"
    },
    {   
                "name" : "Denise",
                "employeeID" : 03,
                "designation" : "Software test engineer"
    },

        {       "name" : "Matthew",
                "employeeID" : 04,
                "designation" : "Software Test engineer trainee"
    },
    {   
                "name" : "Mark",
                "employeeID" : 05,
                "designation" : "Project Manager"
    },
    {   
                "name" : "Karla",
                "employeeID" : 06,
                "designation" : "Associate Project Manager "
    }
]
}
function employeeDetails(){
  var eID = document.getElementById('eid').value; 
  var flag = 0; 
  $("#employee1 tbody").html("");
     if(eID != "" ){
       
           for(var j=0;j<empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails.length;j++){
                   if(empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails[j].employeeID == eID ){
                        flag=1;
                        document.getElementById('pro2').style.display = "block";
                        var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails[j].name + "</td>" 
                                     +"<td>" + empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails[j].employeeID + "</td>"  
                                    +"<td>" + empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails[j].designation + "</td>"
                                    
                       
                    }
            }
        
           for(var i=0;i<employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails.length;i++){
             if(employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails[i].employeeID == eID)
             {
              flag = flag== 1? 2 : 3;
             tblRow = tblRow + "<td>" + employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails[i].phoneNumber + "</td>" 
                                     +"<td>" + employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails[i].emailAddress + "</td>"
  
                                     +"<td>" + employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails[i].region + "</td>" 
                                     + "</tr>";
             }
            
            }
            
    
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#employee1 tbody");
            
            
            
            
             if(flag==0)

                 alert ("Not matched");
             }
             else if(flag ==1)
             {
                alert ("Only Company Details Found");
             }
             else if(flag ==3)
             {
                 alert ("Only Personal Details Found");
             }

     else 
        {
            alert ("Emp id is empty");
        }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div>
Enter Emp id : <input type ="text" id="eid" name="eid"/>
<button id="getEmpdetails" onclick="employeeDetails()"> GetEmployeeDetails</button>
</div>
<div id ="pro2" class="profile2" style="display:none;">
 </br>  <table id= "employee1" border="2">
  <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ID</th>
              <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
         
            <th> Phone Number</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
       </tbody>
   </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have 1 doubt, Is it possible to retrieve from a json value in single search, like we do with java map all ?

Comment: do you mean to search in a single json object  or multiple ?

Comment: now in this code, if I am searching for 3rd employee, for a loop 3 iterations goes, but is it possible to with the single iteration from json

Comment: Here the data structure to be traversed for search is an Array,  in this type of data structure you will have to traverse an element at a time. All the methods $.inArray or .indexOf does the same iteration internally . So i think there is no way that without iteration search can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Example of **single loop** function. Just plug it into your code and you should be golden.

Let me know if it works for you..

```js
function magicMatch(eID, persons, employees) {
  var personsCount = persons.length;
  var employeesCount = employees.length;
  var maxCount = personsCount > employeesCount ? personsCount : employeesCount;
  var person, employee;

  for (var i = 0; i < maxCount; i++) {
    if (!person && i < personsCount) {
      if (persons[i].employeeID == eID) {
        person = persons[i];
      }
    }

    if (!employee && i < employeesCount) {
      if (employees[i].employeeID == eID) {
        employee = employees[i];
      }
    }

    if (person && employee) {
      return [person, employee]; // or whatever return format you want
    }
  }
  
  return [person, employee]; // or whatever return format you want
}

// usage example
var personEmployeeMatched = magicMatch(
  document.getElementById('eid').value,
  employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails,
  empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails
);

// personEmployeeMatched will now contain:
// [{..person..} | undefined, {..employee..} | undefined]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use two separate loops over a loop inside another loop:

```
 function employeeDetails() {
  var eID = document.getElementById('eid').value;
  if (eID != "") {
    var em1, em2;
    for (var i = 0; i < employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails.length; i++) {
      if (employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails[i].employeeID == eID) {
        em1 = employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails[i];
      }
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails.length; j++) {
      if (empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails[j].employeeID == eID) {
        em2 = empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails[j];
      }
    }

    if (!em1 || !em2) {
      alert("Not matched");
      return;
    }

    // use em1 and em2 to render table

  } else {
    alert("Emp id is empty");
  }
}
```

This way the complexity is just O(n) compare to O(n^2) of your current implementation

Comment: This is full of mistakes, won't ever work... Rework or delete.

Comment: You still will always end up rendering the last person and last employee with this code. Does not make any sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this,

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
    var employee= 
       {
  "EmployeesPersonalDetails" : 
    [
       {
           "employeeID":01,
           "region":"Coimbatore",
           "phoneNumber":9087653456,
           "emailAddress":"abc@gmail.com"
       },
       {

           "employeeID":02,
           "region":"Avinashi",
           "phoneNumber":8990908765,
           "emailAddress":"def@gmail.com"
       },
       {
           "employeeID":03,
           "region":"Thippur",
           "phoneNumber":9089898990,
           "emailAddress":"ghi@gmail.com"
       },
       {
           "employeeID":04,
           "region":"Madurai",
           "phoneNumber":9012345990,
           "emailAddress":"jkl@gmail.com"
       },
       {
           "employeeID":05,
           "region":"Thippur",
           "phoneNumber":9067890990,
           "emailAddress":"mno@gmail.com"
       },
       {
           "employeeID":06,
           "region":"Thippur",
           "phoneNumber":9345218990,
           "emailAddress":"pqr@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
    }

var empcmpy={
"EmployeesCompanyDetails" :[
    {   
                "name" : "Mike",
                "employeeID" : 01,
                "designation" : "Software engineer"
    },
    {
                "name" : "Westlee",
                "employeeID" : 02,
                "designation" : "Software engineer trainee"
    },
    {   
                "name" : "Denise",
                "employeeID" : 03,
                "designation" : "Software test engineer"
    },

        {       "name" : "Matthew",
                "employeeID" : 04,
                "designation" : "Software Test engineer trainee"
    },
    {   
                "name" : "Mark",
                "employeeID" : 05,
                "designation" : "Project Manager"
    },
    {   
                "name" : "Karla",
                "employeeID" : 06,
                "designation" : "Associate Project Manager "
    }
]
}
function employeeDetails(){
      var eID = document.getElementById('eid').value; 
      var flag = false;
      var matchemp;
      var mathccomp;
      var empflag=false;
      var compflag=false;
      
         if(eID != "" ){
          for(emp in employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails){
           if(employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails[emp].employeeID==eID){
            empflag=true;
            matchemp=employee.EmployeesPersonalDetails[emp];
            break;
           }
          }
          for(comp in empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails){
           if(empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails[comp].employeeID == eID ){
            compflag=true
            mathccomp=empcmpy.EmployeesCompanyDetails[comp];
            break;
           }
          }
          
          if(empflag&&compflag){
           document.getElementById('pro2').style.display = "block";
                 var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + mathccomp.name + "</td>" 
                              +"<td>" + mathccomp.employeeID + "</td>"  
                              + "<td>" + matchemp.phoneNumber + "</td>" 
                              +"<td>" + matchemp.emailAddress + "</td>"
                              +"<td>" + mathccomp.designation + "</td>"
                              +"<td>" + matchemp.region + "</td>" 
                              + "</tr>";
                 $(tblRow).appendTo("#employee1 tbody"); 
          }
          else{
           alert ("Not matched"); 
          }
         }
         else 
            {
                alert ("Emp id is empty");
            }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div>
   Enter Emp id : <input type="text" id="eid" name="eid" />
   <button id="getEmpdetails" onclick="employeeDetails()">
    GetEmployeeDetails</button>
  </div>
  <div id="pro2" class="profile2" style="display: none;">
   </br>
   <table id="employee1" border="2">
    <thead>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Phone Number</th>
     <th>Email Address</th>
     <th>Designation</th>
     <th>City</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
   </table>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use two different loops and then can break once the conditions have been satisfied as shown above in the snippet

Comment: I have 1 doubt. Is it possible to retrieve from a json in single search, like we do with java map all ?